# Setting crystal report text field on FormLoad

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am using Crystal Report's Crystal Report Viewer on Winforms. On my report there is a text field name `recptNumber`. I put a viewer on WinForm. What I want to set value of it when form loads. I can access value by doing :

`RaseedLayout.secDetails.ReportObjects["txtRepRaseedNumber"]).Text = "۳۴۴۴۵۵";`

but can't set the value at all.

How do I do it?

```
rptRaseed RaseedLayout = new rptRaseed();
MessageBox.Show(((TextObject)RaseedLayout.secDetails.ReportObjects["txtRepRaseedNumber"]).Text);
((TextObject)RaseedLayout.secDetails.ReportObjects["txtRepRaseedNumber"]).Text= "۳۴۴۴۵۵";
RaseedLayout.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
TextObject txt1 = (TextObject)RaseedLayout.ReportDefinition.Sections["YOURSECTIONHERE"].ReportObjects["txtRepRaseedNumber"];

txt1.Text = "۳۴۴۴۵۵";
```

Hope this works!

Comment: How is it different than one I used?

Comment: you have to cast your object as a TextObject like in my example, just try it if is not working give me a feedback! good luck

Comment: Should I call it in formLoad?

Comment: Gotcha! it worked.! What is the difference by adding *ReportDefinition*?

Comment: That's great! ReportDefinition allows you to retrieve all of the Areas, ReportObjects, and Sections in a report :)